# How to define the structure of the angular project,when there are many components?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I'm the new to angular 2.0,and I try to rebuild the old project with angular2.0,but I found if I put each part into a component,the structure of the project become chaos,here is the structure of my project now :

[image]

[image]

and these components are just used by the userManage's component, do I really need to part each one into a small component? or just put them into userManage's component?

Comment: It's up to you if you need smaller components or not, nobody can decide that for you. Why do you have linear structure? Are these components used outside of userManage? If they aren't, they can be put into userManage dir.

Comment: I'm not sure now whether these components will be used by the other.So I just put them in the first level,If they are just used for one components, why do  I stll need to wirte then into a component alone,  why not put them into the parent component?

Comment: If by 'put them into the parent component' you mean that you won't make them a separate component but just a part of the template, this will result in having a huge single component with crappy design that is difficult to develop and maintain. This isn't really specific to components or Angular, just a common OOP thing.

Comment: https://angular.io/styleguide#!#application-structure-and-angular-modules